# Both datacenters continue working when connection between is down

Tags: percona, galera

Suppose we have one galera clusters in two data centers. one with 3 nodes and the other one with two nodes.

When connection between them goes down, 3 nodes datacenter will be primery and continue working.but two node side will stop.

How is it possible for both sides continue working and resync when connection established?

Our data in one center is independent of the other side

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** No

**Discussion:**

That is the "split brain" problem.  That happens when two systems (datacenters, in your question) each accept writes.  When the two parts get back together, there could be conflicting `INSERTs` (etc), such as adding a row with the same `PRIMARY KEY`.  There is no way in InnoDB or Galera to resolve such a conflict.  Instead, they *prevent* it.  In this example, the system that does not have the quorum (the 2-server DC) says "I'd better not accept any writes."

You have a "single-point-of-failure".  If the DC with 3 nodes goes down (yes, DCs *do* go down), you will be offline.  (The 2-node DC won't have a quorum.)

So, to be "fully HA", you need 3 DCs, each with at least one node.  And be sure to weight the nodes to avoid SPOF.  (Eg, 4 nodes spread as 1+1+2 could experience split brain if the 3rd DC goes dark.  Change the "weights" to prevent such.)

See also NDB-Cluster.  It is a MySQL offering that provides for "eventual consistency" as a solution to multiple systems containing the "same" data.

Comment: Thanks Rick , but galera has a way to handle unique primery key conflict,Because it automatically manages it. In NDB cluster is the fourth data node available for writing when it is detached?

Comment: @Behdad - Please tell me more about the PK conflict resolution.

Comment: @Behdad - Are you suggesting mixing InnoDB and NDB?

Comment: it is like one node generating even numbers for pk and another one is generating odd numbers when there is two nodes.It can be configured by auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset in mysql. When there are 3 nodes auto_increment_increment will be 3 and auto_increment_offset would be 1 for node 1,2 for node 2,3 for node 3 and so on.Then there will be no conflict for pks even when there is no connection

Comment: @Behdad - Yes, that solves _that_ problem.  There are others, mostly around `UNIQUE` keys.  With a bit of discipline, you can avoid the problems.